# How do I change the body class in hte _Host.cshtml file of a Blazor Server App?

Tags: html, razor, blazor-server-side

I am writing a Blazor Server app and I have a requirement to dynamically modify the body class which is located in the _Host.cshtml file of my application.

I need to modify this class from different .razor components. I've tried creating a class and injecting it into the startup which is fine for code blocks on the actual _Host.cshtml file but not for the code blocks in the .razor components where I need to call it from.

Essentially, I need to obtain a reference to body class so I can modify it from a child razor page and/or component.

Comment: it is a special reason for adding a `class` to the `body` element? or you can have `div` wrapper to `@Body` in the main layout, and on this `div` you can set `width:100vw` and `height 100vh`. This div will act as body for your pages.

Comment: @LucianBumb I'm using an html template I purchased from an online theme shop and I'm placing that HTML into the _Host.cshtml file of the Blazor Server App. There is an instance where the user can select a check box to change the theme background dark/light. That said, that adds an additional class to the body etc. In Blazor, certain things like modals don't function right for me because they add/remove classes on the body. I was considering writing a function in the base.js and calling the JS interop to invoke from the child .razor component.

Comment: Hi @xrmdevs, Im doing exactly that. I have a template and the template for each different page uses some classes in the body. Did you find a way to do this? Thanks